# Implement a common function accepting argument of two different classes?

Tags: java, generics

I have two classes A and B and they both have a common `field` in them, and I want to create a function in which if I pass Class A object then I want to set that common field value to the passed value and if I pass Class B object then I want to set that common field value to the passed value. Can anyone please tell me how can I do this, I am new to Java `Generic Classes`.

Otherwise I would have to make two different functions `OR` I would have to make an if and else which would decide that passed object belongs to which class ??

**Class A**

```
public class A{

    int footer;

    public void setFooter(int fo) {
         footer = fo;
    }

}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B{

    int footer;

    public void setFooter(int fo) {
         footer = fo;
    }

}
```

**Class D**

```
public class D{

    public void change_footer(T generic_param, int value) {
         generic_param.setFooter(value);
    }

}
```

**Class HelloWorld**

```
public class HelloWorld{

  public static void main(String []args){
    Here I want to call
    A a = new A();
    new D().change_footer(a, 5);

    B b = new B();
    new D().change_footer(b, 5)

  }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: You can make your two classes implement an interface that specifies what you need to do with the field. You don't need generics for that.

Comment: Why do you need generics for this?

Comment: @khelwood And generics in Java won't help you with it either - unlike C++ generics, you can't write specializations in Java.

Comment: @khelwood I just thought that I need to have a generic type parameter because I cannot have a Class A or Class B, parameter. Why do you think that I don't need generics here because as i can't define my parameter type at runtime that is what the use of generics? Isn't it?

Comment: If your two classes implement a common interface, you can use that interface as a method parameter. You don't need generics for simple polymorphism. If they don't have a common interface, generics won't help, because you won't be able to do anything useful with your objects until the compiler knows what type they are.

Comment: If you describe what you precisely need to do, someone can probably tell you precisely how to do it.

Comment: @khelwood I have updated my Question please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And if I got all of the question wrong, and nor A nor B are generic, AND the type of field is fixed.
>   then you mean something like:

```
class D {

    /*public <T extends Super> would be muuuch nicer here as well!*/
    public /*static*/ <T> void change_footer(T obj, int data) {
        //otherwise, you could just cast to Super...and set dat field.
        if (obj instanceof A) {
            ((A) obj).setField(data);
        } else if (obj instanceof B) {
            ((B) obj).setField(data);
        } // else ... ?

    }
}
```

> Original answer:

Easy peasy (the "straight forward" implementation produces the desired results.):

```
class A<T> {

    T daField;

    public void setField(T pField) {
        daField = pField;
    }

    public T getField() {
        return daField;
    }
}

class B<T> extends A {//empty
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        B<Object> testB1 = new B<>(); //
        testB1.setField(new Object());
        System.out.println(testB1.getField());
        B<String> testB2 = new B<>();
        testB2.setField("blah blah");
        System.out.println(testB2.getField());
        B<Integer> testB3 = new B<>();
        testB3.setField(42);
        System.out.println(testB3.getField());
    }
}
```

System.out:

```
java.lang.Object@6d06d69c
blah blah
42
```

It get's (little) more complicated, when you want to instantiate `T`s ...but still possible/other question. :)

> Edit to your comment:

If there's only one common field, then why not:

```
/*abstract */class Super<T> {
     T daField;

    public void setField(T pField) {
        daField = pField;
    }

    public T getField() {
        return daField;
    }
}
```

? ...and:

```
class A<T> extends Super { ... }
class B<T> extends Super { ... }
```

Comment: I can't use `extend` there is only one common field others I don't want to have in my class.

Comment: ...if you want to extend "only 1 field", then you have to introduce a (new, generic) super class with "only 1 field" ..and `extend` that!

Comment: Can you please have a relook at my post, I have edited my post.

Comment: I thought of `generic` but never thought I could just have used `instanceof`. Thank you a lot. Got confused really.